# How to read space-separated 0-9 digits in C?

Tags: c, arrays, io

I am trying to make a program that reads **space-separated positive digits** in C and gives an error message to ANY other format of input.

For example, the following inputs are correct:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
7 6 5 4 3
1 2 3
...
```

For all the other inputs, the program should terminate and an error message should be printed. For example:

```
0 1,2 3 4-5 67 89
0123456789
0a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i
...
```

Here is my attempt:

```
...
int inputArr[999];
int length = 0;
char c = getchar();

while ( c != '\n' ) {
    if ( isdigit(c) ) {
        inputArr[length] = c - '0';
        length++;
    } else {
        printf ("Wrong Input Format!\n");
    }
    c = getchar();
    if ( c != ' ' ) {
        printf ("Wrong Input Format!\n");
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
...
```

but this gives an error message even when the input is correct.

**Update:**

When I input the following:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I expect the program not to give me any error messages but I get exactly 10 error messages (After removing the line `exit(1);`). I am assuming it is one error message for every character after 1 and (that is 9 messages) and 1 message for the '\n' character at the end.

Comment: Thanks, but not quite: The purpose of the title is mainly for the listing on the index, to get people's attention. But the body of the post should also be a question. It should state precisely what you expected, what went wrong, and your particular question as narrowed down as possible. Don't just ask "why doesn't this work", but ask specifically "why doesn't X do Y by Z, when the manual claims that X should do Y (citation)", etc.

Comment: Your logic seems pretty broken. You have all those `if`s, but they don't have `else`s. So you basically have no chance of spotting an error at the right time. And your newline detection is incomplete, too. And you have no mechanism to detect the end of the input.

Comment: I added else statements but I still don't understand why I get an error message when input is in the correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void e() { puts("Bad input."); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

int main(void)
{
    for (int c1 = 0, c2 = 0; c1 != EOF && c2 != EOF; )
    {
        c1 = getchar();
        if (c1 == EOF || c1 == '\n') continue;   // file or line ends in "x "
        if (!isdigit(c1)) e();

        c2 = getchar();
        if (c2 != EOF && c2 != '\n' && c2 != ' ') e();

        printf("Got input: '%c'.\n", c1);
    }
}
```

This version permits trailing spaces at the end of a line. If you *don't* want to allow trailing spaces (i.e. `"1 2"` is OK but `"1 2 "` is an error), change the first condition to:

```
if (c1 == EOF || c1 == '\n' || !isdigit(c1)) e();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will play around with it. I am thinking about making multiple spaces acceptable input format.

Comment: @user6005857: You probably want `scanf` then rather than doing all this manually.

Answer (score 1):

A flag could be used to signal when a digit is read and prevent consecutive digits. Consecutive spaces will not be rejected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void)
{
    int inputArr[999];
    int c = 0;
    int length = 0;
    int gotdigit = 0;

    while ( ( c = getchar ( )) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        if ( isdigit ( c) && !gotdigit) {//found digit and no prior consecutive digit
            inputArr[length] = c - '0';
            length++;
            if ( length >= 999) {
                break;
            }
            gotdigit = 1;//set true to prevent consecutive digits
        } else {
            if ( c == ' ') {
                gotdigit = 0;//set false. found space so next digit is ok
            }
            else {//not a space or was consecutive digit
                printf ("Wrong Input Format!\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```